# create file object using file path instead of input file form

Tags: autodesk-forge

most if not all Forge samples used input file form to get input file like below:

```
$("#inputFile").change(function () {
_fileInputForm = this;
if (_fileInputForm.files.length === 0) return;
var file = _fileInputForm.files[0];
```

}

what if i want to achieve the same result without UI at all? something like below:

```
const data = {
    ModelId: "dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLjNSTzhMWmtUVGVHM3p1M1FoNjRGM3c_dmVyc2lvbj0x",
    ElementId: [{ UniqueId: "ca5762b5-0f46-4a2f-8599-1d1a5dd19a81-00024b8c" }],
};
var file = new File([data], "whatever.json", { type: "application/json" });
```

data is manually copied from whatever.json, how to do it via code? thanks

Comment: figured out, no UI but still need server i.e. route endpoint, any better way?

Comment: this is a general rule with web programming for security: The client side (in a browser page) is prohibited to open a local file directly (for protecting local).  you must use File API (pop out file dialog to select file) .

Comment: put the file in server does not mean the client accesses the local file directly. It means the file is managed on server side, which is allowed to be access from client side.  this is secured .

Comment: right, local file still needs oauth from server side to be accessible from client side even without specific browser UI i.e. select file dialog, thanks XD